# Border Radius / Overflow Problem in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, opera, css

I have a site that uses a lot of border-radius for layout. The issue is compared to a working version (Firefox) in the screenshot below (also I did NOT design this awful thing).

[image]

All the code follows the same format for border radius:

```
border-top-left-radius: 25% 54%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 19% 54%;
```

The only thing I can see is the grey boxes ("main_area") border-radius is actually controlled by a parent, so maybe the grey background is overflowing.

[Here is the link](http://www.interohub.propertylogic.net)

Also note the same error occurs in Opera. I am not using prefixes, just the above css. The layout is also fine in IE9.

Thanks

Comment: It's a bit hard without seeing the rest of the CSS. Plus your link isn't working, could you provide another one?

Comment: @brunn - sorry, corrected the link. The css is quite extensive, I wouldn't know where to start with what to put on, I can pastebin my whole css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage dimensions are calculated based on the default font-size, so use a reset stylesheet or add browser specific font-sizes to the selectors which use percentages, such as:

```
div#container > #main > #main_area > .content > .holder {
  font-size: 10px;
}

/* Firefox reset */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    div#container > #main > #main_area > .content > .holder {
    font-size: inherit;
    }
}

/* IE9 reset */
@media all and (monochrome: 0) { 
   div#container > #main > #main_area > .content > .holder {
    font-size: inherit;
    } 
}
```